# Is it possible to auto-stretch text to width of rectangle?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop

I am using a rectangular text object to "fit" dynamic text in an area of my layout. (If it is too long for one line, it wraps to more.)  Is there a way to have the (changing) text fit the width of the rectangle it is in?  I know I can change the symbol properties and adjust the character spacing (for example), but there doesn't seem to be a way to tell it to automatically determine a spacing that fills the box.

What I'm looking for is like using Maplex labeling on a polygon and setting the spread characters value to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You have to activate the draw toolbar (left click on the gray bar space) There you find Text option and another ones like "rectangle text"